# ServiceStack IContainerAdapter adapting Autofac 5.2.0 version

Tags: c#, servicestack, autofac

I'm trying to upgrade the latest **Autofac** package to `5.2.0`, but not really successfully becasue of interface changes,

From (`Autofac 4.9.4`)

```cs
public static class ResolutionExtensions
{
    public static bool TryResolve<T>(this IComponentContext context, out T instance);
}
```

To (`Autofac 5.2.0`)

```cs
public static class ResolutionExtensions
{
    public static bool TryResolve<T>(this IComponentContext context, out T instance) 
        where T : class;
}
```

The **ServiceStack** package has a **IContainerAdapter** interface (`ServiceStack.Interfaces 5.8.0`)

```cs
public interface IResolver
{
    T TryResolve<T>();
}  

public interface IContainerAdapter : IResolver
{
    T Resolve<T>();
}
```

My **AutofacIocAdapter** implementates this **IContainerAdapter**

```cs
public class AutofacIocAdapter : IContainerAdapter
{
    public T TryResolve<T>()
    {
        if (m_Container.TryResolve<Autofac.ILifetimeScope>(out var scope) &&
            scope.TryResolve<T>(out var scopeComponent))
        {
            return scopeComponent;
        }

        if (m_Container.TryResolve<T>(out var component))
        {
            return component;
        }

        return default(T);
    }
}
```

But got compiling error after upgrading **Autofac**

```cs
Error   CS0452  The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'ResolutionExtensions.TryResolve<T>(IComponentContext, out T?)'
```

Any suggestion to resolve ?

Comment: which file throws this error ?

Comment: Looks like you need to add type constraints to TryResolve . something like ```public T TryResolve<T>() where T : new()```

Comment: @Soundararajan My AutofacIocAdapter.cs. But I cannot modify interface of `TryResolve<T>`. It's already declared by `IContainerAdapter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't be able to call a class with a class constraint from a method without that constraint from C#, but you could use reflection to invoke it.

But your first attempt should be to bypass the API with the constraint. Looking at [AutoFac's implementation of TryResolve](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/04c8f8294d305c6c273cf42d8589e27d0324a6bc/src/Autofac/ResolutionExtensions.cs#L931-L954) will show what APIs they call internally:

```
public static bool TryResolve<T>(this IComponentContext context, out T? instance)
    where T : class
{
    if (context == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
    }

    object? component;

    // Null annotation attributes only work if placed directly in an if statement.
    if (context.TryResolve(typeof(T), out component))
    {
        instance = (T)component;

        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        instance = default;

        return false;
    }
}
```

So you would just need to bypass their generic API with constraints and call the same runtime Type API that they call, something like:

```
public class AutofacIocAdapter : IContainerAdapter
{
    private readonly Autofac.IContainer container;

    public AutofacIocAdapter(Autofac.IContainer container) => 
        this.container = container;

    public T TryResolve<T>()
    {
        if (container.TryResolve<Autofac.ILifetimeScope>(out var scope) &&
            scope.TryResolve(typeof(T), out var scopeComponent))
            return (T)scopeComponent;

        if (container.TryResolve(typeof(T), out var component))
            return (T)component;

        return default;
    }

    public T Resolve<T>()
    {
        var ret = TryResolve<T>();
        return !ret.Equals(default)
            ? ret
            : throw new Exception($"Error trying to resolve '{typeof(T).Name}'");
    }
}
```

Comment: Tested and looks very simple for this answer. Thanks !

Comment: For those migrating to Autofac 6.x note that you'll need to replace the above
`private readonly Autofac.IContainer container;`
with
`private readonly Autofac.IComponentContext container;` and adjust the constructor accordingly to prevent containeradapter resolving from failing with a `Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException`:
Cannot resolve parameter 'Autofac.IContainer container' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Autofac.IContainer)'.